# Fragments over activities for phones android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

What are the `advantages/disadvantages` of using fragments over activities in an application when designing for a phone and tablet?

Should we have activities for phones and fragments for tablets. Is there any advantage of fragments for phones besides making the `code reusable`?

The android dev site http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html says on the phone, the fragments are separated into `different activities.` What then would be the point of using fragments?

Comment: Hi 

The use of fragment is let say if your activity has so many UI task in one screen then it might be possible that you block whole activity life cycle by calling network stuff or any database stuff or gps stuff at same time, so fragment came in picture while you have some many sub task in same screen.We use fragment because it embedded with activity with it own life cycle you can add,remove fragment at run time, so it would reusable component.

Comment: Fragments require API Level 11 or greater if you want for earlier version there is backward compatibility provide by android you can use android-support fragment jar in android.

Answer (score 1):

> ## 1 & 2 what are the purposes of using a fragment & what are the advantages and disadvantages of using fragments compared to using activities/views/layouts ?

Fragments are Android's solution to creating reusable user interfaces. You can achieve some of the same things using activities and layouts (for example by using includes). However, fragments are wired in to the Android API, from HoneyComb, and up. Let me elaborate;

- The ActionBar. If you want tabs up there to navigate your app, you quickly see that ActionBar.TabListener inferface gives you a FragmentTransaction as an input argument to the onTabSelected method. You could probably ignore this, and do something else and clever, but you'd be working against the API, not with it.
- The FragmentManager handles "back" for you in a very clever way. Back does not mean back to the last activity, like for regular activities. It meeans back to the previous fragment state.
- You can use the cool ViewPager with a  FragentPagerAdapter to create swipe interfaces. The FragmentPagerAdapter code is much cleaner than a regular adapter, and it controls instantiations of the individual fragments.
- Your life will be a lot easier if you use Fragments when you try to create applications for both phones and tablets. Since the fragments are so tied in with the Honeycomb+ APIS, you will want to use them on phones as well to reuse code. That's where the compatibility library comes in handy.
- You even could and should use fragments for apps meant for phones only. If you have portability in mind. I use ActionBarSherlock and the compatibility libraries to create "ICS looking" apps, that look the same all the way back to version 1.6. You get the latest features like the Actionbar, with tabs, overflow, split action bar, viewpager etc.

> ## 2

The best way to communicate between fragments are intents. When you press something in a Fragemnt you would typically call StartActivity() with data on it. The intent is passed on to all fragments of the activity you launch.

For more detailed understanding of Fragments check [Link](http://andytsui.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/to-fragment-or-not-to-fragment/)

Comment: Thanks but I did read your post on another link. It doesn't entirely answer my question, I'm afraid. Why exactly does Google suggest another design for phones(different activities)?

Comment: Its because of re usability and flexibility of the fragments and as i have mentioned a link in my answer you can checkout for more details.